# My debian-menu.xml is missing

Tags: debian, openbox

I have a relatively new Debian installation -- when it was first installed, it was without a gui, but I ran `apt-get install xinit` and `apt-get install openbox`, so when I run `startx` I get an openbox session.

My openbox menu is rather limited, and `.xsession-errors` shows

```
Openbox-Message: Unable to find a valid menu file "debian-menu.xml"
Openbox-Message: Unable t o find a valid menu file "/var/lib/openbox/debian-menu.xml"
```

When I check `/var/libopenbox/debian-menu.xml` there's nothing there.
Is it possible to fix it so that openbox can show debian menu items?

Edit:

The following is an excerpt from my `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml` file:

```
<menu>
  <!-- You can specify more than one menu file in here and they are all loaded,
       just don't make menu ids clash or, well, it'll be kind of pointless -->

  <!-- default menu file (or custom one in $HOME/.config/openbox/) -->
  <!-- system menu files on Debian systems -->
  <file>/var/lib/openbox/debian-menu.xml</file>
  <file>debian-menu.xml</file>
  <file>menu.xml</file>
  <hideDelay>200</hideDelay>
  <!-- if a press-release lasts longer than this setting (in milliseconds), the
       menu is hidden again -->
  <middle>no</middle>
  <!-- center submenus vertically about the parent entry -->
  <submenuShowDelay>100</submenuShowDelay>
  <!-- time to delay before showing a submenu after hovering over the parent
       entry.
       if this is a negative value, then the delay is infinite and the
       submenu will not be shown until it is clicked on -->
  <submenuHideDelay>400</submenuHideDelay>
  <!-- time to delay before hiding a submenu when selecting another
       entry in parent menu -->
       if this is a negative value, then the delay is infinite and the
       submenu will not be hidden until a different submenu is opened -->
  <applicationIcons>yes</applicationIcons>
  <!-- controls if icons appear in the client-list-(combined-)menu -->
  <manageDesktops>yes</manageDesktops>
  <!-- show the manage desktops section in the client-list-(combined-)menu -->
</menu>
```

Comment: Is the `menu` package installed?

Comment: @jw013 It wasn't... So I just installed it, and the "/var/lib..." error seems to have gone away, but I still get `Openbox-Message: Unable to find a valid menu file "debian-menu.xml"`

Comment: @jw013 I've edited my post and added the stuff. And yes, I have the `/var/lib/openbox/debian-menu.xml` file. The second line in `debian-menu.xml` mentions something about it being an automatically generated file.

Comment: @jw013 Actually I think I've solved the problem. I am not sure exactly what was wrong, but I ran `cp /etc/xdg/openbox/* .config/openbox/` again after installing `menu`, and everything works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `menu` package provides the Debian menu and must be installed.

Answer (score 3):

By your description, it looks like the `openbox` package doesn't operate correctly if the `menu` package is not installed before it. The easy fix would be for it to `Depend:` on `menu`. As Openbox is a light-weight window manager intended for small systems that may not want `menu`, it would be better to fix Openbox's configuration. Please check whether you can reproduce this issue on a pristine installation of Openbox (save your configuration files and purge the package). If you can, please check the [Debian bug tracker](http://bugs.debian.org/openbox) to see if this issue has been reported, and if not, report it.

Comment: `openbox` only *suggests* `menu`.  I'd be interested in seeing how such a bug report to request a `depends` would be triaged as one could argue that `openbox` is still useful without the Debian menu.  (I have never looked at the auto-generated Debian menu except to see what was in it out of curiosity.)  The error messages seen by the OP are probably caused by the combination of `openbox` not depending on `menu` yet still including `debian-menu` in its default configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

The menu package provides the Debian menu and must be installed.

1. Enable the breezy Universe repository
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install menu